# Xamarin Profiler not visible in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So, The question is pretty much self explanatory. I can not see Xamarin Profiler in Analyze menu of Visual Studio. Its Enterprise version of 2017. The profile is installed and I can see it in Start Menu and can open it from there.

Answer (score 0):

my problem is exactly like yours;

Xamarin Profiler was available before last week in my visual studio enterprise 2017, and suddenly  removed and bundle assembly to native code in android option is disappeared too. 
until now I can't find its reason and a solution

do you find any solution?

Comment: I did some more research into it. Found out there is a notorious bug in Xamarin responsible it. It has happened to a lot of people in past. Recently also, it has happened to a lot of people so I guess this recent one has been caused again by a similar bug. No solution for me so far. I'll post if I find an answer.